# Нужны ли запятые в обороте "не иначе как"?

Tags: пунктуация

-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правило, нет, поскольку это цельное выражение. Но иногда бывает, что на "иначе" падает логическое ударение, и тогда перед "как" нужна запятая. Например: "*Не иначе, как утром и вечером*".